# How do I maintain the distance traveled when changing the size, knowing that I do not want to add height?Flutter

Tags: flutter

Code:

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
                      children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 350,
                              // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/7,

                              child: Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,

                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(23)),
                                ),

                                child:    Column(

                                  children: [

                                    const Text(""),

                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),

                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
                                          ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: getFontSize()),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                                          // maxLines: 10,


                                        ),
                                      ),


                                    ),

                                    const Text(""),


                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [

                                        Expanded(
                                          child: SizedBox(

                                            height: 100,
                                            width: 200,

                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                              child: Card(
                                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                                elevation: 10,

                                                child: ListTile(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    //مشاركه للذكر
                                                  },

                                                  leading: const Icon(Icons.share),
                                                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                                                  title:  const Center(
                                                    child: FittedBox(
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        "C",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontSize: 30,
                                                            fontFamily: 'mess'),
                                                      ),

                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: SizedBox(

                                            height: 100,
                                            width: 200,

                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                              child: Card(
                                                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                                                elevation: 10,

                                                child: ListTile(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    if(mins>0) {

                                                      _incrementCounter();

                                                      //الاخفاء هنا
                                                      //return   ;


                                                    }else{




                                                    }




                                                  },

                                                  leading: const Icon(Icons.sunny_snowing),
                                                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                                                  title:  Center(
                                                    child: FittedBox(
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        '$mins g ',
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontSize: 30,
                                                            fontFamily: 'mess'),
                                                      ),

                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),




                                  ],

                                ),

                              ),

                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Explanation of the problem

I have a size box. I have specified the width, but I do not want to add a height. This is because when the user enlarges the text, I want the size box to go down to the bottom. The code has one problem, which is when the user goes down to read, and if he wants to change the size, the distance traveled goes back to the top, and I I don't want that.  The distance traveled should remain constant even when changing the size. Sorry for the length, and thank you in advance

pictures

[pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRO0m.jpg)

Comment: I hope you understand me

Comment: the reason its scroll to the top is because, when you change the font size, your `Listview` or any scollview widget are `rebuild`. maybe you can just rebuild single child by separate them into new widget different class, or you can control the scolling.

Comment: pmatatias, please can you explain to me how to write the code

Comment: I used CustomScrollView because I want to scroll to the bottom